# How do I assign a variable in Bash whose name is expanded ($) from another variable?

Tags: bash

I have a part of script as below.

```
notify() {
printf -v "old_notif" "%d" "$notif_$2"
now=$(date +%s)
fark=$((now - old_notif))
echo $old_notif
if [ -z $old_notif ]; then
```

.....

```
x1=$(date +%s)
export "notif_$2=$x1"
```

I call notify with 2 parameters.

```
notify xyz klm
```

I create a dynamic variable in function with export. And the main script is in the `while` loop.
My question is how can I use `notif_$2` variable in `if` check? 
Or how can I assign it's decimal content to another variable?
In the example I tried with `printf` it doesn't assign the content.

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***TL;DR:*** One way is `local tmp="notif_$2"; printf -v "old_notif" "%d" "${!tmp}"`.

You are trying to expand a [parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) (in this case, a variable) whose name must itself be obtained by expanding another parameter (in this case, a positional parameter). Furthermore, the positional parameter must be expanded, then concatenated with the text `notif_`, to produce the text that must then itself be expanded.

Bash lets you do this cleanly with **indirect expansion** or a **nameref**.

The first two sections of this post show drop-in replacements for your `printf -v` command, using those techniques. The remaining sections are optional; they further explain these features and what you can do with them.

#### Way 1: Indirect Expansion

[Indirect expansion](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-dereference-variable-names-inside-bash-functions) is the most similar, conceptually speaking, to what you have written. Instead of the `printf -v` command you have now, you can use these two commands:

```
local tmp="notif_$2"
printf -v "old_notif" "%d" "${!tmp}"
```

`local` makes the `tmp` parameter local to the shell function. If for some reason you don't want that, just omit the word `local`. The parameter doesn't need to be called `tmp`.

Indirect expansion is covered in [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).

#### Way 2: Namerefs

Another way is to use [a nameref.](https://books.google.com/books?id=pIyYCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT31&lpg=PT31&dq=bash%20%22declare%20-n%22&source=bl&ots=1KIXiJd5xE&sig=z6Cn-N0e_6clsDrWACVJd6Y2Emk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLusmr1uHUAhUIxoMKHUnbAYwQ6AEIUTAI#v=onepage&q=bash%20%22declare%20-n%22&f=false) A nameref refers to a parameter. You create it from the name of the parameter, but once created, it behaves as though it is that parameter when you read from or write to it.

To use a nameref, replace your `printf -v` command with:

```
local -n ref="notif_$2"
printf -v "old_notif" "%d" "$ref"
```

Passing the `-n` option to `local` or `declare` causes the newly introduced parameter to be a nameref. Notice that, in the `printf` command, you will use ordinary parameter expansion (`$ref`) -- not indirect expansion -- because the shell performs the indirection automatically for the nameref.

You do need `local` or `declare` here, because `-n ref="notif_$2"` by itself would be an error and `ref="notif_$2"` by itself wouldn't make a nameref. `declare` without the `-g` option in a shell function behaves like `local`, so you can use that style if you prefer. Or, in the unusual case where you wanted the nameref to be usable after the function returned, you could use `declare -g` **Thanks to [G-Man](https://askubuntu.com/users/325633/g-man) for [pointing out a mistake about this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926450/how-do-i-assign-a-variable-in-bash-whose-name-is-expanded-from-another-varia/930104?noredirect=1#comment1917757_930104) in an earlier version of this answer.**

(Depending on your needs, it might even make sense to use a nameref for more than just these two lines. To learn how, read on.)

Namerefs are covered in [3.4 Shell Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) in the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).

#### Detailed Explanation: How Indirect Expansion Works

Shell features are most easily demonstrated through interactive use, but positional parameters (like `2`, expanded via `$2`) don't have quite the same meaning outside a shell function, and the `local` builtin doesn't work at all outside a function (you would use `declare` instead, or nothing).

So, to start with a simplified example, suppose you are working interactively in your shell and you have run:

```
x=foo
export "notif_$x=1234"
```

After you run that, `1234` is stored in the parameter `notif_foo`. (It also exports that parameter as an environment variable.) We can see this by inspecting `notif_foo`:

```
echo "$notif_foo"
```

This outputs `1234`.

Your scenario is analogous to not knowing *what* is in the `x` parameter. (In your case, you instead don't know what's in the second positional parameter passed to your shell function. I'll get to that soon.)

But you can build the parameter name and put it in another parameter:

```
y="notif_$x"
```

Now `y` holds `notif_foo`, so you can use indirect expansion on `y`, which looks like this:

```
"${!y}"
```

That expands to `1234`, just as if you had used `"$notif_foo"`. But you don't need to know `$x` is `foo` to use it.

For example, this will assign `1234` to `old_notif`:

```
old_notif="${!y}"
```

If you need to format the contents of `$notif_foo`, you can do that, too. For example, you can use `printf` if you need it. This command is similar to the `printf` command in your question, and has the effect of assigning `1234` to `old_notif`:

```
printf -v old_notif '%d' "${!y}"
```

(It also works in your original quoting style, i.e., `printf -v "old_notif" "%d" "${!y}"` has the same effect.)

Of course, this relies on the `y` parameter being suitably assigned first.

To write your shell function, you will replace `$x` with `$2`, and you will probably want to use the `local` builtin to prevent your temporary variable--which I will now call `tmp` instead of `y`--from leaking out of the function's scope.

```
local tmp="notif_$2"
printf -v old_notif '%d' "${!tmp}"
```

Or, using the quoting style you used in the question:

```
local tmp="notif_$2"
printf -v "old_notif" "%d" "${!tmp}"
```

#### Detailed Explanation: How Namerefs Work

To try out namrefs interactively, you must use `declare -n` rather than `local -n` (because `local` only works--or is needed--inside the body of a shell function).

As before, suppose you have run:

```
x=foo
export "notif_$x=1234"
```

Thus `$notif_foo` expands to `1234`. You can create a nameref to the parameter named by the result of expanding `"notif_$x"`:

```
declare -n y="notif_$x"
```

Now `y` refers to the name `notif_foo`, and ordinary parameter expansion on `y` will automatically dereference that name, thereby expanding the `notif_foo` parameter. That is, this expands to `1234`, just as if you had used `$notif_foo`:

```
"$y"
```

To write your shell function, you will replace `$x` with `$2`, and I recommend using `local` instead of `declare`. I suggest also using a somewhat more descriptive name than `y`; for a short function with no other nameref declarations, `ref` is probably adequately clear.

```
local -n ref="notif_$2"
print -v old_notif '%d' "$ref"
```

Or, with the quoting style you've been using:

```
local -n ref="notif_$2"
print -v "old_notif" "%d" "$ref"
```

#### Namerefs are Powerful

A nameref lets you do more with its referred-to parameter than just read from it. You can also, for example, write to it:

```
x=foo
declare -n y="notif_$x"
y=1234
```

The second command creates a nameref to a parameter that might not yet exist. That's no problem! It will be created when you first assign to it, even if that assignment is *through* the nameref.

The third command *looks* like it assigns `1234` to `y`, but really it assigns it to `notif_foo`. Now both `$y` and `$notif_foo` expand to `1234`. `$notif_foo` expands to `1234` because that's the value stored in `notif_foo`; `$y` expands to `1234` because `y` is a nameref for `notif_foo`.

Suppose you *want* to know what `y` refers to, though. That is, suppose you want to get `notif_foo`, rather than `1234`, from `y`. Well, you can, because with a nameref, indirect expansion has the opposite of its usual effect. This expands to `notif_foo`:

```
"${!y}"
```

#### In your function, you could introduce `notif_$2` through a nameref.

This suggests another way to deal with `notif_$2` in your function: you can introduce it through a nameref, and use the nameref for each subsequent access.

Currently you have:

```
x1=$(date +%s)
export "notif_$2=$x1"
```

As an alternative, you could use:

```
x1=$(date +%s)
local -n ref="notif_$2"
ref="$x1"
export "${!ref}=$ref"
```

That's more complicated that necessary, though, since presumably you only created the `x1` parameter because `export "notif_$2=$(date +%s)"` is hard to read. `ref="$(date +%s)"` is just as simple, though, so you can omit the `x1=` line and write:

```
local -n ref="notif_$2"
ref="$(date +%s)"
export "${!ref}=$ref"
```

It occurs to me that you might have been using `export` just to assign the parameter for use in your shell. If you don't actually need to export it to child processes, then you can just use the first two lines, and that's simpler than what you have.

If you *do* need to export it, use all three. It's still a bit more complicated than what you have... but it may let you simplify *the rest* of your function, because, afterwards:

- Instead of having to write `notif_$2`, you can just write `ref`.
- This works even in scenarios where writing `notif_$2` is inadequate. That is, it is no longer necessary to do anything special (like Way 1 and Way 2 above) to expand the parameter whose name is the result of expanding `notif_$2`. Just write `ref`.
- This even works for writing -- and creating, and unsetting -- the parameter. (After the point of declaration, `ref=text` writes to and can even create the referred-to parameter; `unset ref` unsets the referred-to parameter.)

If you're going to use a nameref throughout your whole function, you may want to think of a more meaningful name for it than `ref`. (The best name will, of course, be determined by the task you are writing the function to carry out.)

Comment: Dear Eliah, thank you for your detailed explanation. I really appreciate.

Comment: (1) You might want to mention that namerefs are available only in bash version 4.3 and higher. (2) You say “You cannot omit `local` here, though [… if …] you wanted the nameref to be usable after the function has returned, you could replace it with `declare`.”  Either you’re mistaken or I’m misunderstanding you.  If I do `declare -n ref=whatever` in a function, then that nameref exists only until the function returns.  [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381761/80216#381782) says that (in bash) variables declared (with `declare`, without `-g`) in functions are local to the function.

Comment: @G-Man Thanks. What I said about `local` was wrong *and* unclear; I've edited. You're right that `declare` without `-g` in a bash function works like `local`. Also, my goal was to say that namerefs must be declared, which didn't come through. As for which bash versions support namerefs, I'm reluctant to add that. Trying and failing to use namerefs shouldn't cause harm, and no supported Ubuntu release packaged so old a version of bash even when the post was new. Similarly, my (and others') AU poss tend not to warn about portability, outside non-EoL Ubuntu, of `find`, `echo`, and other commands.