# Is it possible to write a bash function to change directory by passing the name of a directory variable?

Tags: bash, functions

I want write a function which changes the working directory by passing the name of a directory variable which has already been established like :

```
foo () {
   cd $"$1"
}
```

However when I try , for example, foo links
I get
-bash: cd: links: No such file or directory

Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: See [How do I assign a variable in Bash whose name is expanded ($) from another variable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926450/how-do-i-assign-a-variable-in-bash-whose-name-is-expanded-from-another-varia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use variable indirection:

```bsh
foo () {
    cd "${!1}"
}

dir=/mnt
foo dir
pwd  # /mnt
```